# Getting a 404 error when trying to connect to socket io/express server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-status-code-404

I'm having a lot of trouble connecting to a socket io and express server with the following code. 
I can connect to the web page/api in the browser but as soon as i try to connect with a socket connection from the index.html the I get the errors as follows

this is my 'server.js'

```
var WebSocketServer = require('uws').Server,
    express         = require('express'),
    path            = require('path'),
    app             = express(),
    server          = require('http').createServer(),
    createEngine    = require('node-twig').createEngine;

app.engine('.twig', createEngine({
    root: __dirname + '/public',
}));

app.set('views', './public');
app.set('view engine', 'twig');

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(require('./api'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use("/admin", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use("/admin/scss", express.static(__dirname + '/scss'));
app.use("/admin/vendors", express.static(__dirname + '/vendors'));
app.use("/admin/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use("/admin/build", express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

app.use("/scss", express.static(__dirname + '/scss'));
app.use("/vendors", express.static(__dirname + '/vendors'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use("/build", express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {

    ws.on('join', function () {
        console.log('SOMEONE JUST JOINED');
    });

    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('stopping client interval');
        clearInterval(id);
    });
});

server.on('request', app);

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:8080');
});
```

and this is my index.html file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var so = io.connect('http://192.168.***.***:8080/');

so.on('connect', () => {
    so.emit('join');
});

</scrip>
```

this is the error I keep getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LfHXP1O. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://192.168.4.149:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

and sometimes I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

solution:

```
<script>
      var host = window.document.location.host.replace(/:.*/, '');
      var server = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':8080');
      server.onmessage = function (event) {
        updateStats(JSON.parse(event.data));
      };

      server.onopen = function (event) {};


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use socket.io on the client side to connect to a plain webSocket server on the back-end.  You can't do that.  socket.io is a layer on top of a webSocket so you either need to use a plain webSocket to connect to a plain webSocket server or socket.io in the client to connect to a socket.io server on the back-end.

I'd suggest you change your server to use socket.io for a socket.io server instead of a plain webSocket server.

The errors you are getting are because the socket.io client is expecting to be able to issue a certain http request that the socket.io server will handle, but since you don't have a socket.io server, that URL request is not handled on the server.

Comment: HI there. Thanks for your reply. 
1. I though var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server}); was an implementation of socket.io in the back end but just optimized. 
2. Saying that I wanted to keep the server as is then how exactly would I be able to connect to it from the client side?
Im quite new with all the porting and websockets etc